# Using Google Accounts for Authentication and Google APIs in Compute Engine

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

The Google App Engine standard environment allows easy integration with Google accounts for user authentication, Cloud Datastore and with APIs such as Gmail API, Google Calendar etc.

Are these same features available in Compute Engine also? I mean can I deploy a web application in a Tomcat container in a Compute Engine VM and use Google Accounts for authentication, Cloud Datastore for persistence and APIs such as Google Plus and Google Calendar for reading users' personal information?

I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/activate) URL that says Cloud Datastore can be used from Compute Engine but could not find similar documentation about usage of Google Accounts for authentication and usage of APIs like Google Plus and Google Calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

You can use all Google APIs (Gmail API, Google Calendar etc) from tomcat and from any other web container. You simply need to provide the credential to connect to the Google APIs. [HERE](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow) how can you obtain the credential on a server side web application, please note that the documentation it's not referring to any specific web container.

Appengine provides out of the box a simpler way to authenticate Google user through the [UserServiceFactory](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserServiceFactory). This service it's not available outside the AppEngine Enviroment because it comes with the AppEngine SDK.

In order to use the Google Cloud Datastore from outside of the AppEngine environment you need to use the [Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi). With this api you will be able to access the Datastore service.

Comment: Thank you Simone. I assume this means irrespective of whatever authentication/authorization mechanism is used by a web application, a Google OAUTH flow can still be triggered for logged in user provided the logged in user can be mapped to a Google account. And after the OAUTH flow is completed/approved by the user, its access token can be used to invoke any Google API in the authorized scopes. In effect one can use a simple RDBMS based user management and still have access to Calendar, Gmail APIs etc. as well as Cloud Datastore - via Remote APIs as suggested. Could you please confirm?

Comment: Yes exactly, I hope that answered you question

Comment: Thank you @Simone Tallevi-Diotallevi.